# Decimal/binary/hex converter

Tags: c++, integer, number-systems

I've finally finished my converter and have determined that it works, but I'm trying to make it cleaner and/or more practical (primarily with the `switch` statements).  I could probably put more things into functions, but it'll be needless unless I can replace the `switch` statements with something simpler.

Are there other methods of performing these conversions that would use less code, or are these methods good enough?  I am also using `unsigned long long` so that I can work with large numbers, but I can always change that if it may not be the best thing to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef unsigned long long uInt64;

uInt64 calculatePower(uInt64, uInt64);
uInt64 binaryToDecimal(std::string);
uInt64 hexadecimalToDecimal(std::string);
std::string decimalToBinary(uInt64);
std::string binaryToHexadecimal(std::string);

int main()
{
    std::string binary, hex;
    uInt64 decimal;
    uInt64 choice;

    std::cout << "\n\n* Decimal -> Binary & Hex (1)\n";
    std::cout << "* Binary -> Decimal & Hex (2)\n";
    std::cout << "* Hex -> Binary & Decimal (3)\n\n";
    std::cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "\n> Decimal Input: ";
        std::cin >> decimal;
        std::string binaryOutput = decimalToBinary(decimal);
        std::string hexOutput = binaryToHexadecimal(binaryOutput);
        std::cout << "\n  Decimal Output: " << binaryOutput;
        std::cout << "\n  Hex Output    : " << hexOutput << "\n\n\n";
    }

    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "\n> Binary Input: ";
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::getline(std::cin, binary);
        uInt64 decimalOutput = binaryToDecimal(binary);
        std::string hexOutput = binaryToHexadecimal(binary);
        std::cout << "\n  Hex Output    : " << hexOutput;
        std::cout << "\n  Decimal Output: " << decimalOutput << "\n\n\n";

    }

    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        std::cout << "\n> Hex Input: ";
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::getline(std::cin, hex);
        uInt64 decimalOutput = hexadecimalToDecimal(hex);
        std::string binaryOutput = decimalToBinary(decimalOutput);
        std::cout << "\n  Binary Output : " << binaryOutput;
        std::cout << "\n  Decimal Output: " << decimalOutput << "\n\n\n";
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}

uInt64 calculatePower(uInt64 base, uInt64 exponent)
{
    uInt64 total = 1;

    for (uInt64 iter = 0; iter < exponent; iter++)
        total *= base;

    return total;
}

uInt64 binaryToDecimal(std::string binary)
{
    uInt64 decimal = 0;
    uInt64 exponent = 0;
    std::string::reverse_iterator iter;

    for (iter = binary.rbegin(); iter != binary.rend(); iter++)
    {
        if (*iter == '1')
            decimal += calculatePower(2, exponent);

        exponent++;
    }

    return decimal;
}

uInt64 hexadecimalToDecimal(std::string binary)
{
    uInt64 decimal = 0;
    uInt64 exponent = 0;
    std::string::reverse_iterator iter;

    for (iter = binary.rbegin(); iter != binary.rend(); iter++)
    {
        switch (*iter)
        {
        case '1':
            decimal += calculatePower(16, exponent);
            break;
        case '2':
            decimal += (2 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case '3':
            decimal += (3 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case '4':
            decimal += (4 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case '5':
            decimal += (5 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case '6':
            decimal += (6 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case '7':
            decimal += (7 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case '8':
            decimal += (8 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case '9':
            decimal += (9 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case 'A':
            decimal += (10 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case 'B':
            decimal += (11 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case 'C':
            decimal += (12 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case 'D':
            decimal += (13 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case 'E':
            decimal += (14 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        case 'F':
            decimal += (15 * calculatePower(16, exponent));
            break;
        }

        exponent++;
    }

    return decimal;
}

std::string decimalToBinary(uInt64 decimal)
{
    std::string binary, newBinary = "";
    std::string::reverse_iterator iter;
    uInt64 remainder;

    while (decimal > 0)
    {
        remainder = decimal % 2;

        if (remainder == 0)
            binary += '0';
        else if (remainder == 1)
            binary += '1';

        decimal /= 2;
    }

    for (iter = binary.rbegin(); iter != binary.rend(); iter++)
    {
        newBinary += *iter;
    }

    return newBinary;
}

std::string binaryToHexadecimal(std::string binary)
{
    std::string hex, newHex = "";
    std::string::reverse_iterator iter;

    uInt64 incr = 1;

    uInt64 exponent = 0;

    uInt64 total = 0;

    for (iter = binary.rbegin(); iter != binary.rend(); iter++)
    {
        if (*iter == '1')
            total += calculatePower(2, exponent);

        if (incr == 4)
        {
            switch (total)
            {
            case 1:
                hex += '1';
                break;
            case 2:
                hex += '2';
                break;
            case 3:
                hex += '3';
                break;
            case 4:
                hex += '4';
                break;
            case 5:
                hex += '5';
                break;
            case 6:
                hex += '6';
                break;
            case 7:
                hex += '7';
                break;
            case 8:
                hex += '8';
                break;
            case 9:
                hex += '9';
                break;
            case 10:
                hex += 'A';
                break;
            case 11:
                hex += 'B';
                break;
            case 12:
                hex += 'C';
                break;
            case 13:
                hex += 'D';
                break;
            case 14:
                hex += 'E';
                break;
            case 15:
                hex += 'F';
                break;
            }

            incr = 0;
            exponent = -1;
            total = 0;
        }

        incr++;
        exponent++;
    }

    newHex += "0x";

    for (iter = hex.rbegin(); iter != hex.rend(); iter++)
    {
        newHex += *iter;
    }

    return newHex;
}
```

Comment: Are you willing to the code tied to ASCII? If so, the easiest simplification I see is to use c - '0' to get offsets. Like `decimal += (*iter - '0') * calculatePower(16, exponent)`. (Technically not tied to ASCII; just requires that '0'...'9' be contiguous.)

Comment: I am, if it'll go in place of the `switch` statements.  Even what I have now is clear, but very bloated.  Maybe I can work something out with a `char` array...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*system* is bad. Either use `getchar()`, set your IDE to pause after execution, or use a terminal when running a terminal program.

---

The `typedef` for `uint64` should just be `uint64_t` from `stdint.h`.

---

Your input reading should be checked. For example, `std::cin >> choice;` can fail. It should be

```
if (!(std::cin >> choice)) { /* handle this */ }
```

If you're thinking you're ok because choice is checked to be either 1, 2, or 3, you're not ok. You're just almost certainly ok. If the read fails, choice will still have an indeterminate value. That could mean 1, 2, or 3.

---

You can basically replace all of your `ToDecimal` functions with `strtoul` (C >= C89) or `strtoull` (C >= C99). An `unsigned long` is only gauranteed to be 4 bytes, so you'll want the `strtoull` version.

---

Similarly, `sprintf()` can convert to hex for you (format `llX`).

---

If you're not willing to do that, but you're willing to assume that '0'...'9' is always contiguous, you can use the class `value = c - '0'` shortcut.

As an example, you could simplify your beastly `hexidecimalToDecimal()`:

```
uint64_t hexadecimalToDecimal(const std::string& binary)
{
    uint64_t decimal = 0;
    uint64_t power = 1;
    std::string::const_reverse_iterator iter;

    for (iter = binary.rbegin(); iter != binary.rend(); iter++)
    {
        const char ch = std::tolower(*iter);
        if (ch >= 'a') {
            decimal += (ch - 'a') * power;
        } else {
            decimal += (ch - '0') * power;
        }
        power *= 16;
    }

    return decimal;
}
```

---

When arguments are NOT modified, they should be passed as `const` references. This avoids the overhead of copying. (And it's part of a larger concept called const-correctness.)

---

I tend to put arguments names in declarations. In this situation, it's a marginal concern since all of the functions have very obvious parameters, but in some cases, it can be quite confusing to see a declaration and wonder what the different params are.

---

Unless performance is tight, I'd be tempted to implement everything in terms of decimal. For example, `binaryToHex(bin): decimalToHex(binaryToDecimal(bin))`

---

Speaking of performance, if you wanted to, you could inline the exponent calculations instead of recalculating it from scratch every time.

```
uint64_t binaryToDecimal(const std::string& binary)
{
    uint64_t decimal = 0;
    uint64_t p = 1;
    std::string::const_reverse_iterator iter;

    for (iter = binary.rbegin(); iter != binary.rend(); iter++)
    {
        if (*iter == '1')
            decimal += p;
        p *= 2;
    }

    return decimal;
}
```

(And if you're really paranoid about performance, you'll want that `iter++` to be `++iter` as it avoid a potential copy)

---

If for some odd reason you don't want to do that, `calculatePower()` can be optimized in many different ways:

- Use the `double` version and just cast back to `uint64_t`.
- Use powers of 2 and abuses of shifting (x<sup>16</sup> = `x << 4`)
- Use [divide and conquer style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1505791/567864)

---

> ```
> remainder = decimal % 2;
>
> if (remainder == 0)
>     binary += '0';
> else if (remainder == 1)
>     binary += '1';
> ```

As remaining can only be 0 <= `remainder` <= 1, the `else if` is unnecessary. I would just use:

```
if (decimal % 2 == 0) {
    binary += '0';
} else {
    binary += '1';
}
```

---

You can use std::reverse (from `<algorithm>`) rather than your manual reversal loop.

Example:

```
std::string decimalToBinary(uint64_t decimal)
{
    std::string binary;
    while (decimal > 0)
    {
        if (decimal % 2 == 0)
            binary += '0';
        else 
            binary += '1';
        decimal /= 2;
    }
    std::reverse(binary.begin(), binary.end());
    return binary;
}
```

Comment: I've added what I have now.  I still need to simplify `binaryToHex`, or I can just keep it this way.  I'll look at the input validation later.

Comment: Should be `<cstdint>` instead of `<stdint.h>` and if you want to be really pedantic, `std::uint64_t`. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @Yuushi Yeah, I definitely should have mentioned the C++11 version (no sign that he's using C++11, but he everyone should probably be headed that direction). With `stdint.h` though, `std::uint64_t` is actually wrong. Non c* version is guaranteed to put the types in the global namespace, but not in `std`.

Comment: Yeah, that needs a logical connection in there - `<cstdint>` => `std::uint64_t` since it's the other way around (guaranteed to be in `std` but not in global). Have to love the interop rules sometimes...

Comment: Eh makes sense since name spacing is almost always desirable, but C doesn't have namespaces. What I don't get is why stdint didn't get a C++ version until C++11 (though I'm sure I can google it -- they probably just thought the types could be global...)

Comment: In C++11 If a read fails. The value is guaranteed to be zero. From **n3376**: See [istream.formatted.arithmetic] => [facet.num.get.virtuals] Stage 3: `The numeric value to be stored can be one of: 1: zero, if the conversion function fails to convert the entire field. ios_base::failbit is assigned to err. 2: ....`

Comment: There is no assumption that char 0-9 are consectuive: From **n3376** See [lex.charset] `the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.`

Comment: @Corbin, I can confirm to you that I'm NOT currently on C++11.  When I tried to use `strtoull`, my IDE did not recognize it (but it did recognize `strtoul`, although I would have to use `unsigned long` instead).  I currently use Visual C++ 2010 Express, if that helps any.  Either way, I may prefer to decline from using that function since I need to see the logic in my own program.  On the contrary, I am interested in seeing how `sprintf` can help me here, once I figure out how to use it.  I'm open to other methods (shorter than mine), of course.

Comment: I am now writing a function called `hexadecimalToBinary` that entirely uses ASCII offsets (different offsets if the hex value is 0-9 or A-F) and my existing `decimalToBinary` function.  I'll post that here sometime.

Comment: @LokiAstari Ah, did not know either of those were guaranteed. Will edit my answer accordingly in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You repeated calls to `calculatePower` are rather inefficient.  There is no need to
call this every time round a loop.  In `binaryToDecimal`, you could do this:

```
    std::string::const_reverse_iterator i = b.rbegin();
    for (int exp = 0; i != b.rend(); ++i, ++exp) {
        if (*i == '1') {
            decimal += (1 << exp);
        }
    }
```

and in `hexadecimalToDecimal`:

```
    std::string::const_reverse_iterator i = h.rbegin();
    for (int exp = 0; i != h.rend(); ++i, exp += 4) {
    {
        int n = 0;
        if ((*i >= '0') && (*i <= '9')) {
            n = *i - '0';
        }
        else if ((*i >= 'a') && (*i <= 'f')) {
            n = *i - 'a';
        }
        else if ((*i >= 'A') (*i <= 'F')) {
            n = *i - 'A';
        }
        decimal += (n << exp);
    }
```

For `binaryToHexadecimal` it would be easier to convert binary to machine
(what you call decimal) and then machine to hex.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but is there a reason you aren't converting to `unsigned long long` first with any of a set of functions, then formatting the output in a separate set of functions?  e.g.:

```
unsigned long long fromHex(std::string& number);
unsigned long long fromBin(std::string& number);
unsigned long long fromDec(std::string& number);
std::string toHex(unsigned long long number);
std::string toBin(unsigned long long number);
std::string toDec(unsigned long long number);
```

It seems a bit inconsistent to use the term "decimal" for an `int` in system representation.  It would just be confusing, if not for the problematic differences in function signatures between each of the `XtoY` functions.  If it was more uniform, you could:

```
class NumberFormat {
public:
    static virtual unsigned long long from(std::string& number);
    static virtual std::string to(unsigned long long number);
    std::string description;
}
```

Then, you can make your list of number formats more declarative; construct an array, output the descriptions, and have the user pick what will effectively become an index into the array for the source format.  Then read the destination format and numeric string, in either order.

As it stands, the input method is needlessly coupled to a finite set of formats and their names, as is the source/destination pairings.

I once wrote a hex-by-default calculator/expression evaluator in assembly, so I'm the last guy that's going to call a wheel-reinvention foul on you; in fact, I like the general theme of your code because I've never seen a number formatter that covers absolutely everything, like your binary output's adding leading zeroes to pad 4 bit groups.  Bravo on making a wheel that spins exactly like you want it to.

With regard to the conversions themselves, I see more twos complement math than is necessary.  In particular, I see several `%`s while converting to binary.  If I'm interested in a number's binary representation, I will probably find the equivalent ones complement operations in your code just as readable, if not more so.  The sequence:

```
if (usersDecimal & 1) {
    newBinary += '1';
} else {
    newBinary += '0';
}
usersDecimal >>= 1;
```

just screams "I am extracting a single bit from the number and printing it!" to me, whereas with `%` and `/=`, it seems like you might be calculating something at first glance.  And, if you *really* like brevity:

```
newBinary += ((usersDecimal & 1) + '0');
usersDecimal >>= 1;
```

will get the job done.  Not particularly clean, though.

Other than that, the particulars of the conversions are good.  Stuff like constants for `DIGIT_OFFSET` strike a good balance between efficiency and readability.